# change on CustomListItem

Tags: python, kivy-language

I use CustomListItem with BoxLayout vertical and 
BoxLayout horizontal with one  ListItemLabel and 4 ListItemLaButton respectively
BoxLayout vertical one ListItemLabel.

when I get items in CustomListItem it shows me all ListItemLabel and ListItemLaButton.I would like to know if I can with the on_press one ListItemLaButton to show me the ListItemLabel on BoxLayout vertical 
and not when I do add items on CustomListItem.

Comment: Yes of course you can but show us what you have done so far, so we can help you